# matlab state space simulation

Tags: matlab, controls, simulation

Right now I have two control law state equations for a 3rd order state-space system. In matlab, therefore I have two A-matrices. I used lsim() to test the functionality of each control law. However, right now I need to determine when to switch from one control law to another. If you are interested, I can explain more.

Comment: With the question as it stands, we can't even be sure if we are interested :-) Please be much more specific, and include essential parts of code

Comment: YOU should sell your question. If you provide enough information, people will try to answer.